# Plot region using non-boolean functions

Tags: plotting

I am struggling with the following problem. I want to plot in 3D a function that is only defined implicity by ArgMax. However, I want to restrict the plotting range of the function depending on a condition, which, itself, depends on ArgMax. Therefore, it seems that I cannot use RegionPlot, because the function is not Boolean. Here is a code, which generates the graph below.

```
E1 = -((4.` (0.` - 0.005` M^2 + p))/(0.03` + 0.005` M^0.5)) +     100. (-0.1` - 0.005` M^2 + p - 0.33333333333333337` e p) + 100.` (-0.1` - 0.005` M^2 + p + 0.33333333333333337` e p); 
p1test[M_] = 0.1` + 0.002/(0.01 + 0.005` M^0.5) + 0.005 M^2; 
E2 = (3333.3333333333335` (-8.000000000000001*^-7 +          0.01 (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (-0.04 (0.1` + 0.005` M^2) + 0.02` p + 0.02` (1 + e) p)))/(0.0008` + 0.03` (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5)) + (    66.66666666666667 (-0.00008` + (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (-0.04 (0.1` + 0.005` M^2) + 0.02` p + 0.02` (1 + e) p)))/(0.0008` + 0.03` (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5`));
p2test[M_] = ( 0.04` (0.002` + (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (0.1 + 0.005` M^2)))/((0.02` + 0.02` (1 + e)) (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5`));
E3 = (3333.3333333333335` (-0.000029999999999999997` + 0.01` (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (-0.1 - 0.005` M^2 + p + e p)))/( 0.04` + 0.005` M^0.5) + (    66.66666666666667 (-0.003` + (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (-0.1 - 0.005` M^2 + p + e p)))/(0.04` + 0.005` M^0.5`);
p3test[M_] = ( 0.003` + (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5) (0.1 + 0.005` M^2))/((1 + e) (0.01` + 0.005` M^0.5`));
Plot3D[{(1 - UnitStep[p1test[FindArgMax[E1, {M, 10}]] -p])*FindArgMax[E1, {M, 10}], (1 -UnitStep[p2test[FindArgMax[E2, {M, 10}]] -p])*FindArgMax[E2, {M, 10}], (1 -UnitStep[p3test[FindArgMax[E3, {M, 10}]] -p])*FindArgMax[E3, {M, 10}]}, {e, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red,Yellow, Green}, AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyEpsilon]", "p"}, PlotRange -> {0,6}, BoxRatios -> 1,PlotLegends -> {"Business as usual", "Wait-and-see","Churning"}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

[image]

My goal is to suppress the vertical part and the zero values, which are irrelevant (and unattractive).

Yet, if I implement, instead,

```
Plot3D[FindArgMax[E1, {M, 10}], {e, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Green}, AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyEpsilon]", "p"}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, BoxRatios -> 1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},RegionFunction -> Function[{e, p, M}, FindArgMax[E1, {M, 10}] > p]]
```

I get the following error message:

```
Message[Plot3D::invregion, Function[{e, p, M}, FindArgMax[E1, {M, 10}] > p][Identity[#1], Identity[#2], Identity[#3]] &]
```

Thank you very much for your kind help

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include definitions for `E1, E2, E3` as well as `p1test, p2test, p3test`. Thanks.

Comment: Please include definitions as copy-paste-able Mathematica code. The idea is that the forum participants should be able to replicate the difficulty you face in their own notebooks. This way the answers become more focused. Thanks.

Comment: Please delete all comments. Press the `Edit` button under your post and add these details to the question such that others can `copy` and `paste` one block of code to their notebooks to replicate the difficulty you face. An additional necessary step would be: Once you include definitions, start a new notebook; Goto menu, `Evaluation->Quit Kernel->Local` to start a fresh kernel. Now copy and paste from your post to see if the plot is drawn on a fresh kernel. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience - I followed your recommendations and checked the code, it is running ok.

Answer (score 1):

- The result of `FindArgMax` is a list, we need to use `First` or `[[1]]` to extract its value;
- It seems that we should explict define `E1` in `FindArgMax`.

```
f[e_, p_, M_] = E1;
SeedRandom[1];
Function[{e, p}, FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]] > 2 p] @@@ 
 RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}]
```

> `{True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True}`

- But the `RegionFunction` still not so effect then `UnitStep` or `ConditionalExpression`.
- `RegionFunction`

```
Clear[f];
f[e_, p_, M_] = E1;
Plot3D[FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]], {e, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Green}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"ε", "p"}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{e, p}, FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]] > p]]
```

- `UnitStep`

```
Clear[f];
f[e_, p_, M_] = E1;
Plot3D[UnitStep[FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]] - p]*
  FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]], {e, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Green}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"ε", "p"}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

- `ConditionalExpression`

```
Clear[f];
f[e_, p_, M_] = E1;
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]], 
  FindArgMax[f[e, p, M], {M, 10}][[1]] > p], {e, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Green}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"ε", "p"}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and numerous solutions!